# If there was no Glaciation, what would the USA great Lakes look like?

Tags: plate-tectonics, lakes, watershed

I guess, what they looked like before Glaciation could also work as an answer.

Everything I have seen on the lakes only mention their post-glacial forms even when some of them mention that they formed on rifts and shears. Do we just know that the tectonic activity wasn't sufficient to form any Lakes at at those times in the past or have I just not come across the right resources yet?.